# What's advantage to use var in the variable declaration?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between using var and not using var in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

For the code, I found it is no need to declare variable using var. the following are both working

```
// with var
var object = new Object();

// without var
object = new Object();
```

what's the difference between those two?

Comment: take a look in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript

Comment: This is the exact duplicate as pointed out by Daniel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the key difference is if you don't use `var` keyword, your variable will be global, even if you defined it in some nested function.

`var` defines a scope for that variable. Using a global or not depends if you want to use your object across multiple scopes or not, but globals are strongly discouraged in favour of namespaces that reduce the global scope pollution.

Answer (score 3):

if you use var in the wide javascript outside of any function is not important because

```
var a
```

it's the same with

```
window.a
```

but inside a function

`var a` is a private variable of the function while a points to `window.a` ( global )

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use the `var` keyword you are declaring a global variable. If you use it, you are declaring the variable inside the current scope.

For example:

```
function foo() {
    o = new Object();
}

foo();
alert(o); // you can access the o variable here
```

This is very bad because you have basically polluted the global scope.

In contrast:

```
function foo() {
    // the o variable is accessible only inside the current scope which
    // is the foo function
    var o = new Object();
}

foo();
alert(o); // error => o is not accessible here
```

Conclusion: **always** specify the scope of your variables using the `var` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Using `var` makes the variable local to the function